# What happens if I put an 1.5V ram stick in a 1.65V rated Motherboardslot?

Tags: memory, motherboard, bios, voltage

I'm going to bulid my new gaming rig pretty soon. 
I allready got my DDR3 Ram sticks(KVR16N11K2/16 by Kingston).

Is it possible to put those in a Motherboard which has 1.65V Rated RAM-Slots(the Motherboard I'd like to buy is the X79 Extreme6 by Asrock)?

I know, that the RAM-Voltage is Adjustable in the BIOS. 
So, the actual question is: what is the default setting for the RAM-Voltage on this motherboard.

Thanks for your answers.
Have a nice day

Comment: The default is 1.64v

Comment: There are some rules and limits in life you can ignore. Voltage is not one of those.

Comment: Ramhound, you just wrote "the default is 1.64v"  I have checked wikipedia and there is no mention of 1.64v anywhere. There is a mention of 1.65V in the DDR4 page. I think you got the number wrong when you tried to correct him,  or you made a typo and didn't read your own comment.

Comment: @barlop - Yes;  I should have typed 1.65v which I trust is the default on this motherboard if that's what the user claims it to be.  Why are you looking at a Wikipedia page instead of the specifications for the motherboard which is what I looked at?  What does a DDR4 have to do with a motherboard with only DDR3 DIMMS slots?

Comment: I looked at the first two listed supported memory modules and they are both 1.65v  This means the motherboard WILL likely default to that voltage.  So you should place memory that is expecting 1.65v or greater ( its safe to provide less then the require voltage )

Comment: @Ramhound  Because googling for 1.65v and the number you wrote and wikipedia, brought it up and was quick and more than enough to just tell you why I thought you got the number wrong. (i'd have preferred if wikpedia had thrown up a DDR3 page but it didn't matter).  I didn't need to take an interest in a particular motherboard(an interest that wouldn't be of much use to me), to give me good reason to think you had got the number wrong in that first comment of yours.

Comment: The number really wasn't that important.  If you realized it was a typo, the author realized it was a typo, really wasn't worth pointing out.

Comment: Withdrawing my answer; clearly PC RAM is a lot more resilient than the older server and workstation RAM I remember from that last time I had to deal with hardware (it's been several years).

Comment: Not just that, but modern sysems are *explicitly* designed to use low voltage ram, and in many scenarios, its a safe/sane default.

Answer (score 2):

From what I've seen over years of using random desktop RAM in random computers, if it's the right type/ (DDR3, DDR, etc) and it fits in the slot, then it should work (at least set to auto in the BIOS). If the motherboard accepts "DDR3" RAM, then it should accept any DDR3 compliant RAM.

Here's a snippet from [Wikipedia that mentions DDR3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/DDR3_SDRAM) voltage, hardly a definitive source, relevant nonetheless:

> 1.5 V or 1.35 V for DDR3. The 1.5 V supply voltage works well with the 90 nanometer fabrication technology used in the original DDR3 chips. Some manufacturers further propose using "dual-gate" transistors to reduce leakage of current.
>
> According to JEDEC, 1.575 volts should be considered the absolute maximum when memory stability is the foremost consideration, such as in servers or other mission-critical devices. In addition, JEDEC states that memory modules must withstand up to 1.975 volts before incurring permanent damage, although they are not required to function correctly at that level.

(I don't know why you'd want to over-volt your ram anyway, would it even get faster? Maybe gain 10% faster ram, while still waiting 100 times longer than even the slowest ram for data to transfer from a HD or network anyway)

And, the [newegg product page for the motherboard](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16813157289) specifications says it uses "DDR3 2400+(OC)/2133(OC)/1866(OC)/1600/1333/1066" ram. And the [newegg ram page](http://www.newegg.com/Product/Product.aspx?Item=N82E16820239291) says it's "DDR3 SDRAM DDR3 1600" which is in the MB list, so it should be fine.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I Dont actually want to run the modules at this voltage. But Ive got to turn the system on so I can enter the BIOS and turn back the voltage to 1.5V...

Comment: If the BIOS has been cleared (removing the battery for a while should do that) then it *should* default to the lowest/safest voltage. Motherboards are geting pretty good at NOT overclocking/overvolting and "rolling back" to defaults if something goes wrong (at least it seems)

Comment: Yeah, it'll work. Wikipedia's writeup on the subject is a bit skimpy tho :/

Answer (score 0):

The power regulation on the board, and any "rated" capability for it and the ram slots, is not going to set the voltage high, unless the ram chips tell it to, and that doesn't happen even with extreeme ram until the user selects the high end profile for the ram. So it is not a problem.

The default setting for most of these motherboards your talking about is to aquire the whole timing and even the voltage information from the ram chip itself. The SPD is data stored on the ram module itself that tells the motherboard what timings it is supposed to use, with all the newer stuff  and overclocking boards the voltage the motherboard sets it by default or in the AUTO setting is what it aquired from the ram module itself.
 Beyond that you could manually undervoltage or overvoltage it as desired, by taking it off the auto setting.

It is usually XMP profiles that push the memory divisor up, could lower the timing some , and could raise the voltage. I have not seen any of the overclocking (type) motherboards default to a high voltage, and they do not default to an XMP profile. (althought they will default to what the ram told them).

These added profiles are to push the speed to the max it can go, which might include pushing up the voltage, not all configurations of XMP in all situations with all modules added at all manners of overclocking and voltage adjusting will be fully 100% stable.  (a likely reason why these are added/extra profiles and not default)
The added (xmp) profiles also do not require a "higher voltage", some ram modules will be happy at thier high profile at the normal voltages, and the motherboard will set it that way. (then you could have to adjust it yourself off auto, to get stable anyway).

When setting up or adjusting or testing or overclocking, people are alwasy starting with the normal , default settings, and a normal profile for the ram. It is usually only after they get things going and working correct that they will apply the higher profiles and any needed voltages to achieve them. I have never read about anyone who with a defaulted bios/uefi where the motherboard itself set for the extreeme profiles  (although someone else may have owned and adjusted the board before you got it).

Voltage increase or not, the survivability of it when run hard and voltaged high that way will have some to do with the cooling.

Beyond all that many of the high end newer motherboards also have a ram testing timing routine at post or multi-post (why is it post looping) where the motherboards own software will adjust the ram when it fails to test out on post. I do not think any of the motherboards are set to adjust the voltage in that procedure, only to make the timing more loose so it will post/test so it can boot.

Answer (score 0):

It just works - I've got 16gb of the stuff in my desktop, and [Puget system has a great writeup on DDR3L which covers the advantages, and disadvantages of the stuff](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Technology-Primer-Low-Voltage-RAM-150/).

Your system will detect the lower voltage rating and adjust accordingly, assuming its new enough, and since its lower voltage, its likely to run cooler, and use less power. You don't want to/need to overvolt the ram. It performs comparably to regular ram with less poweruse at its defaults.

You lose out on memory overclocking ability ([But in most cases high speed ram is not really needed](http://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/articles/Breaking-the-Hype-of-High-Frequency-RAM-142/)) and its a little costlier *but* it runs significantly cooler than normal ram.

Some SODIMM based systems may *only* work with the low voltage systems - for example NUCs.

There's also a ultra low voltage varient of DDR3, but I'm not sure how compatibility with those is like.